# Choosing a value for random_state argument in scikit-learn linear regression

Tags: linear-model, scikit-learn

A value of 324 is provided without explanation in a linear regression tutorial that I'm following. I checked to see if this was the number of samples, but they did not match.

Edit: My apologies for such an ill-formed question. The random_state argument is for scikit-learn's train_test_split function.

From the documentation, "If int, random_state is the seed used by the random number generator" so I can see that generating a random number is involved
and I'm fairly certain that the utility of generating random numbers is to randomize the samples allocated to training/testing, but what I don't understand is why 324 was chosen.

The tutorial is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PjbTG5BNzL0&t=601s

Comment: This can't be answered without a link to the tutorial.

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate of another thread that at first sight may seem very different from what you're asking, but it provides *all* the answers for your concerns if you read carefully.

Comment: TLDR; you can pick any value you want, people usually choose for the seed some number they like for whatever reason. IMPORTANT: this is not a hyperparameter, so don't tune it.

Answer (score 3):

As found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28069274/4497476) answer by [elyase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1330293/elyase)

> If you use random_state=some_number, then you can guarantee that the
>   output of Run 1 will be equal to the output of Run 2, i.e. your split
>   will be always the same. It doesn't matter what the actual
>   random_state number is 42, 0, 21, ... The important thing is that
>   everytime you use 42, you will always get the same output the first
>   time you make the split. This is useful if you want reproducible
>   results, for example in the documentation, so that everybody can
>   consistently see the same numbers when they run the examples. In
>   practice I would say, you should set the random_state to some fixed
>   number while you test stuff, but then remove it in production if you
>   really need a random (and not a fixed) split.